# Magento 2 Product Details Column in Sales order Grid

Tags: magento2, custom-column-grid, order-grid

I need to extra column to Sales Order Grid that displays product name or product SKU.

Comment: @Prince Patel It is n't working with ver. 2.2.3. I replaced Vendor/Modules and Test\Test to Hello/MyModule and setup:upgrade then deployed static content but no changes affected on the grid. Do I need to make any more changes ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136639)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136639)

Comment: This is working, but now if i am exporting csv the sales orders, product column is empty there whereas the product column has values in the grid, how to resolve this for exporting csv?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158413)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create `sales_order_grid.xml` at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="products" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Create `Products.php` at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Products.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Test\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Products extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$items) {
                $productArr = [];
                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($items["entity_id"]);

                foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                    $productArr[] = $item->getSku();
                    //$productArr[] = $item->getName(); //Get product name
                }
                $items['products'] = implode(' - ', $productArr);
                unset($productArr);
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Now remove var/ and your output will look like:

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @prince-patel.
You solution worked but with a minor glitch.
The product array $productArr was not reseting properly and hence showing previous products which resulted in long strings as the orders grew.

So I made some change

line 38:  $productArr = array();
line 48:  unset($productArr);

Comment: @AbidMalik Yes, you are right. You should reset array. I updated my answer.

Comment: I am yet getting repeating product details on the order grid after using above code. Can you help me for the same @PrincePatel

Comment: @Sumilsanghavi you need to move `$productArr` in foreach loop Check updated answer

Comment: Will it work with FILTER?

Comment: @AbidMalik what is the difference between my answer and Sumil sanghavi answer?

Comment: @PrincePatel nothing actually, I think we all copied your answer only. There was only 1 mistake of resetting array earlier, which i think you fixed. Thanks to you All the way!

Comment: How to make it working with filters?

Comment: @PrincePatel this works fine thanks +1 :)! How can we use Custom Product attribute (Supplier Code [which is not exists in the order table] ) instead of showing SKU in this example ?

Comment: @SagarPPanchal Get product id from `$item` object and use productRepository to get product attribute data.

Comment: @PrincePatel thanks! Really appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is was $productArr = []; is defined above the foreach loop of the data items. i have added below the main foreach loop after that working cool. Thanks.

```
 <?php

 namespace Test\Test\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

 use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
 use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
 use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
 use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
 use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Products extends Column {

protected $_orderRepository;

protected $_searchCriteria;

public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = [])
{
    $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}

public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {

        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$items) {
            $productArr = [];
            $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($items["entity_id"]);

            foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                $productArr[] = $item->getSku();
            }
            $items['products'] = implode(' - ', $productArr);
        }
        unset($productArr);
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello How to make this product sku searchable in order grid, because they are not directly associated with order table